# Prevent OpenLayers ClickEvent from firing on Popup closeButton

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, markers, events

```
    My Code to add popups as selectControl to a Layer. Works fine! 



map.addLayer(window.markerLayer);

// SelectControl für Marker --> Popup
window.selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
        [ window.markerLayer ]);
map.addControl(window.selectControl);

window.selectControl.activate();


// code of: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html#displaying-popups
```

function onPopupClose(evt) {

```
// 'this' is the popup
selectControl.unselect(this.feature);
```

}

function onFeatureSelect(evt) {

```
feature = evt.feature;

var html_popup = "some html code";

popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("featurePopup", feature.geometry
        .getBounds().getCenterLonLat(), new OpenLayers.Size(250, 220),
        html_popup, null, true, onPopupClose);

feature.popup = popup;
popup.feature = feature;
map.addPopup(popup);
```

}

function onFeatureUnselect(evt) {
    feature = evt.feature;
    if (feature.popup) {
        popup.feature = null;
        map.removePopup(feature.popup);
        feature.popup.destroy();
        feature.popup = null;
    }
}

..But by clicking the closeButton on the Popup i am creating a new Marker because of this line:

```
    map.events.register("click", map, newMarkerClickEvent);
```

the Method: newMarkerClickEvent creates a new marker on the xy-Position of the event...

How can i prevent from firing the click-Event to the map on clicking the Popup-Button ??

Thanks!